# Column 'column' does not allow DBNull.Value

Tags: c#, excel, sqlbulkcopy

As the title says, when import excel file to my db it show error. I can't seem to find anything wrong in the codes.

Here's my code in the controller:

**HttpPost:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImportGrade(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    string filepath = "/excelfolder/" + filename;
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/excelfolder"), filename));
    InsertExceldata1(filepath, filename);
    return View("Grade");
}
```

**Connector:**

```
private void ExcelConn(string filepath)
{
    string constr = string.Format(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};
    Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""", filepath);
    Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);
}
```

**Saving Excel to DB:**

```
private void InsertExceldata1(string filepath, string filename)
{
    string fullpath = Server.MapPath("/excelfolder/") + filename;

    ExcelConn(fullpath);

    string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", "Sheet1$");

    OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(query, Econ);

    Econ.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Econ);

    Econ.Close();
    oda.Fill(ds);

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
    objbulk.DestinationTableName = "StudentGrade";
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("StudentNumber", "StudentNumber");
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("CourseName", "CourseName");
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Midterm", "Midterm");
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Finals", "Finals");

    con.Open();
    objbulk.WriteToServer(dt);
    con.Close();
}
```

**Excel Data:**

[image: My Excel Data]

**Error:**

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Column 'StudentNumber' does not allow
>   DBNull.Value.

I appreciate it if someone can help me. Regards!

Comment: Sounds like an issue in your data and not in your code. Do you have any `NULL` values in `StudentNumber`?

Comment: @Zac my table doesn't have data on it and as for my excel that's the only data I have. Do I delete my table and create it again?

Comment: Have you tried to debug and checked what data you have in `dt`? Maybe all StudentNumber column cells are empty or maybe you have additional empty rows in DataTable.

Comment: Why don't you process the excel on memory using the Open XML SDK? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Comment: I fixed it. I deleted and create a new table then I created a new excel file. Thank you for your responses